# Zooming Issues with glutMouseWheelFunc

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, glut, freeglut

I tired implementing a simple zoom in/out using the `glutMouseWheelFunc` in VC++. I am  able to achieve the zooming in/out but while doing so, the axes(GLlines) tend to disappear after zooming more than a certain level.

Am using the `glutMouseWheelFunc` to increase/decrease z- axis value in `glTranslatef`.

I have defined 'z' of  `glTranslatef` for  as camera distance:

```
float cDist= 30.0f; //  camera distance
```

Then used it in glTranslatef as,

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -cDist);
```

in display function below.

```
void display(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //clear the screen to black
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);//clear the color buffer and the depth buffer
    enable();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -cDist);
    glRotatef(xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    ---------------
    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-500, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(500, 0, 0);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0, -500, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 500, 0);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, -500);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 500);

    glTranslated(-xpos, 0.0f, -zpos); //translate the screento the position of our camera
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glutSwapBuffers(); 
    }
```

Afterwards, I defined wheelfunc as,

```
void mouseWheel(int button, int dir, int x, int y)
{
    if (dir > 0)
    {
        cDist = cDist++;
    }
    else
    {
        cDist= cDist--;
    }

    return;
}
```

and called it in main function with `glutMouseWheelFunc(mouseWheel);`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMovement); 
    glutMouseWheelFunc(mouseWheel);---- here
    -----
    ---
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Is this approach of zooming in proper? if not, what could be the alternative ? Also how can I define axes(lines I drew) to full extent of the screen?

Comment: What are your near and far planes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. Seems like I missed up setting up proper depth value for `gluPerspective`. Once I increased the depth value, zoom out/in was working fine